# Writing an event observer to a SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, soap, soap-api-v1

I have a module, which grabs the customer information everytime a customer is updated.  Right now, the customer data is stored in the var log file and I want to send this information to a SOAP API, that was created for me through our software.

I have been provided with a URL for our webservice (http://pop.example.com/DPAPIServices/DPAPIServices.asmx)

and then an example of the SOAP message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dpap="http://www.example.com/DPAPIServices">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <dpap:UpdateCustomer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dpap:aRequest>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:Username>DPAPI</dpap:Username>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:Password>password00</dpap:Password>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerNumber>123</dpap:CustomerNumber>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerName>Cust Name</dpap:CustomerName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerAddress1>Cust Addr1</dpap:CustomerAddress1>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerAddress2></dpap:CustomerAddress2>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerCity>Cust City</dpap:CustomerCity>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerState>FL</dpap:CustomerState>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dpap:CustomerZip>33701</dpap:CustomerZip>
            </dpap:aRequest>
        </dpap:UpdateCustomer>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My observer method, looks like this:

```
<?php
class Mage_Customerupdate_Model_Observer 
{
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $billingaddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        // just check if there is a billing adress
        if ($billingaddress) {
            $fon = $billingaddress->getTelephone(); 
            $street = $billingaddress->getData('street'); 
            $city = $billingaddress->getCity();
            $region = $billingaddress->getRegion();
            $postcode = $billingaddress->getPostcode();
        }
        Mage::log("{$name} ({$customerId}) ({$fon}) ({$street}) ({$region}) ({$city}) ({$postcode})", null, 'customerupdate.log', true);
    }
}
?>
```

I am new to observer events, so maybe this is not how it should be done, but I figured out that I should at least give it a try before coming to you all.